# apache forward ip/port to local domain

Tags: ubuntu, apache2

First i want to apologize if i am not using all the correct terminology, all this network and linux stuff is brand new to me so using tutorials to learn as i go. I work with vb.net and c# so i've been able to pick this stuff up pretty quickly, i just don't fully understand the linux file structure or commands yet.

I have some web services running on an old computer running ubuntu server, and they resolve to an ip address and a port number, like 192.168.1.166:6789 brings me to that services web UI.

I also have apache running on this box which is hosting another service so when i visit 192.168.1.166 WITHOUT the port number at the end, it brings me directly to that web UI for that service (for whatever reason this service needed apache to run, the others just work on their own when i run the service on the server and visit ip/port tied to them).

So basically i want to setup apache (or anything else through ubuntu that can do this) that will forward 192.168.1.166:6789 to say "http://myService" or "http://myService.com" so its easier for non-technical people in the house to pull these web UI's up (not sure what format is valid for local urls, again i am a big time newbie with all this). I have 2-3 services on different port numbers i want to do this for.

Is this possible? I did something earlier inside the /etc/apache2/sites-available config file that let me create a link like "192.168.1.166/myService" but i want to eliminate the ip all together and just have a short alpha name for the URL.

Comment: This is just a local machine on my local network, i do not need to reach a real domain outside my LAN. I just want to be able to type in "http://radarr" and have it bring me to 192.168.1.166:7878 when done on the LAN.

Answer (score 0):

You can use URL redirection to make it possible, here you can check with this  [link](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-create-temporary-and-permanent-redirects-with-apache-and-nginx)

Answer (score 0):

You need to access to that service from inside your network or outside it?

If the problem of solve the service name to the correct ip is solved
and I undestood correctly your question you need to configure a virtual host.

https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/vhosts/examples.html

You can answer to "service_nX" using apache (and a configured virtual host) and it can redirect to the correct port.

You will and on ip/port but user only need to know service_nx.

If you want to use this from outside your localnetwork well' it' triky, but let us know.

I hope this answer is useful.

Comment: I just need to access these locally, i tried to edit my .conf file but this did not work: `
`<VirtualHost *:80>`
`    <Directory /var/www/newznab/htdocs/www/>`
`        Options FollowSymLinks`
`        AllowOverride All`
`        Order allow,deny`
`        allow from all`
`    </Directory>`
``
`    DocumentRoot /var/www/newznab/htdocs/www`
`    ErrorLog /var/www/newznab/logs/error.log`
`    CustomLog /var/www/newznab/logs/access.log combined`
`</VirtualHost>`
``
`<VirtualHost *:80>`
`ServerName 192.168.1.164:7878`
`Redirect / http://radarr`
`</VirtualHost>`